# Creating a new VM in VirtualBox that run on CentOS & Windows 10

Tags: linux, centos, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I wish to create VM in VirtualBox that I would be able to use on both a CentOS system, and Windows 10.
I've read online that if you format an external HDD/SSD to NTFS and create the VMs on that drive, you can use it on both platforms. Is this correct? I don't wish to start my work on one platform only to realise I have to completely redo it on the other later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a VM with its virtual disk (vdi) on an external disk on on of the OSes, then create an identical VM on the other OS configured to use the very same vdi file.

Beware that performance probably won't be stellar and that this approach forbids the usage of virtualbox snapshots.

You should also attempt to keep the same version of virtualbox on both side, i.e. if you update it on one side, update it to the same version on the other one too before launching the VM.